# I have two developer CVs. How do I resolve this?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page, stack-overflow-jobs

Today I created a CV on Stack Overflow, and I also set a custom URL for that CV, i.e. [my1st developer cv URL](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/pethaniakshay). It showed on my profile for some time.

After some time I opened Stack Overflow again and found that **visit my Developer cv** link on the profile page was not active and again there was a link of **create your developer CV**. And again I created [a new developer CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/akshay-pethani-457994). So I am confused for that why my first CV is not visible in my profile and still the link of the first CV is alive, and I also want to know from where I can create a custom URL for my public CV.

Comment: Your first CV is linked to one Gmail address, the other to another Gmail address. We can merge them - which one do you want to keep?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to keep my 1st Developer cv because the custom URl that I've set is most importan for me.

Comment: No problem, merging now!

Comment: The second one seems to be more complete; do you want me to simply add the custom URL to that one instead?

Comment: Yes yes If it is possible than I am ready to keep second one with url of 1s one

Comment: What happen ave you merged @DeanWard ? and I want to keep the email address which ended with 412@gmail.com

Comment: I'm in the process of merging now, just making sure I don't remove the wrong things.

Comment: Yes, you've done it. Thanks a lot mr. @DeanWard.

Comment: Is it Create any problem in my profile if I remove my email address ending with 425@gmail.com?

Comment: You can remove that email address, it won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You had two SO accounts with separate email addresses and each one had a CV associated with it. I've removed one of the CVs and added the public URL to the one you wanted to keep.

Comment: I want to remove my 1st email address from entire stack exchange community and want to make google id as a openid.

Comment: Your old address is no longer present, your old and new accounts were merged.